# kotlin read only var within a sealed data class structure

Tags: kotlin

I have a sealed class like so:

```
public sealed class DocumentBody {

    public data class Information(
        val Id: String,
        val name: String,
        val sort: Int = 2
    ) : DocumentBody ()

    public data class Location(
        val name: String,
        val address: String? = null,
        val sort: Int = 3
    ) : DocumentBody()

    public data class Rating(
        val name: String,
        val rating: Int,
        val sort: Int = 3
    ) : DocumentBody()
}
```

for each one of these I want the sort to be defaulted but also not overwritten. Currently this can be overwritten. How can I achieve this within this model?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Sort what, a list of these? Overwrite what? `read-only var` is an oxymoron. Are you asking how to keep a property that's a `List<DocumentBody>` sorted without changing the instance? For that you would need a `val` that's a `MutableList<DocumentBody>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sealed class DocumentBody(
    val sort: Int
) {
    data class Information(
        val Id: String,
        val name: String
    ) : DocumentBody(sort = 2)

    data class Location(
        val name: String,
        val address: String? = null
    ) : DocumentBody(sort = 3)

    data class Rating(
        val name: String,
        val rating: Int
    ) : DocumentBody(sort = 3)
}
```